# MongoDB update nested item by dynamical ID

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongo-shell

Hey i'm trying to update a nested Object in my MongoDB.

They structure is

```
[
 {
  "_id": "5871010d1ff9831574e7178d",
  "created_at": "2017-01-07T14:54:05.791Z",
  "updated_at": "2017-01-07T14:54:05.791Z",
  "place_id": "ChIJ1eTO6eS1vkcRL_mX2RWUKo4",
  "name": "Kunstwerk Restaurant Gummersbach",
  "__v": 0,
  "cooks": [],
  "menus": [
   {
    "58727068ba8d6c04a0ea331f": [
      {
        "intolerances": {
           "intolerance" : "false"
            ...
          },
        "nutritiondata" : [
          {...}
         ],
         "cookname": "testkoch@test.de",
         "menuname": "MenünameX"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The nested ID in menus is another ID of a MongoDB document which is created dynamicly.

I try to update the menuname, but cant access it, since mongo always returns null or doesnt find the element since in need to search for only the key not the key - value pair.

What i tested so far:

```
db.restaurants.update({ 'menus.58727068ba8d6c04a0ea331f', { $set : {"menus.$.menuname" : "test"}}});

db.restaurants.findOne({ 'menus.58727068ba8d6c04a0ea331f' : "58727068ba8d6c04a0ea331f"});

db.restaurants.find({ menus : { $elemMatch : {"58727068ba8d6c04a0ea331f": "58727068ba8d6c04a0ea331f" }}});

db.restaurants.findOne({ menus : { $eq : "58727068ba8d6c04a0ea331f" }});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So thanks to suzo i figgured out the solution.
The MongoShell code that works:

```
db.restaurants.update({"_id" : ObjectId("5871010d1ff9831574e7178d")}, {$set: {"menus.58727068ba8d6c04a0ea331f.0.menuname" : "testName"}});
```

UPDATE:
Since my field is Mixed type, this isn't updating without getting marked!. So here is the complete correct code:

```
 Restaurant.findOne({ _id : req.body.r_id }, function(error, restaurant){
    if(error) console.log(error);

    for(var i = 0; i < restaurant.menus.length; i++){
          restaurant.markModified('menus');
        if(restaurant.menus[i][req.params.id] != undefined){
            restaurant.menus[i][req.params.id].menuname = req.body.name;
        }

        if(i == restaurant.menus.length-1){
            restaurant.save();
            res.json(jObj);
        }
    }

  })
```

Comment: Cool. Looks like it's the same as my answer but, my question is what if we don't know the index of the array ?

Comment: updated my answer :) ran into the problem the whole time since i figured my first answer. So my solution is to look which key isnt undefined. Since i'm havin only unique keys in there, this method works.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$set` method as shown below :

```
db.restaurants.update({"_id":"5871010d1ff9831574e7178d"}, {$set: {"menus.58727068ba8d6c04a0ea331f.0.menuname":"test"});
```

This will work only if you know the index of the item in the array that is being updated.
Check this [**Page**](https://www.nodechef.com/docs/cloud-search/updates-documents-nested-in-arrays), it has some good examples on updating multi level nested arrays, hope it will help.

Comment: thanks for the response, so i could possibly use the $ as an placeholder for an object? As example menus."THE ID".$.menuname?

Also in your example the mongoshell only response with ...  . So that didnt work?

Comment: It expects the array field in the query, Are you getting any error ?

Comment: No just The 3 points. Ich think as auch pending result... But no error message accures

Comment: ahh i see your mistake. "restaurants" was missspelled and one bracket was missing. now there is a error message. "Too many positional (i.e. '$') elements found in path 'menus.$.58727068ba8d6c04a0ea331f.$.menuname"

Comment: Ok. One thing you can do is, if you know the index of the array that you want to update, `db.restaurents.update({"_id":"5871010d1ff9831574e7178d"}, {$set: {"menus.58727068ba8d6c04a0ea331f.0.menuname":"test"});
`

Comment: I've updated my answer , check if its working and check the link I've mentioned in the answer, that might help.

Comment: Thanks for your help :) found the solution this night by myself with your advise

Comment: Cool . Good to know that, what's the answer by the way?